# Hybrid suspend on HP DV7

Tags: suspend, hp-pavilion

I want to enable Hybrid suspend on my system. Can someone point me to the right info? Plus, I read something about it not working, but is that really true? Or just a system by system issue? Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[s2both](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/uswsusp) (provided by uswsusp) is one way to do it. [pm-suspend-hybrid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/pm-action.8.html) is another. I'm not aware of any outstanding issues for either program that isn't model- or configuration- specific.

That being said, I have [this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/143579/ubuntu-hibernate-resume-fails-pm-resume-from-disk-failed) with pm-suspend-hybrid. The accepted answer there doesn't work for me. s2both resumes correctly, but shuts down my laptop instead of putting it to sleep correctly per [this confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/uswsusp/+bug/94418). I think my issues with these methods are related to my hardware.